# Tableau: Same Day Last Year Auto Filter

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to compare yesterday's data to the same day the year before.  For example, yesterday is 11 November 2018.  I want to compare to 12 November 2017 (same day but the year before).  I am wanting this to be applied automatically on the filter so all I need to do is open the file and verify the numbers are correct before sending off the report.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many Tableau functions that manipulate dates. A couple in particular are relevant to your problem:

- Today() - returns the current date
- DateAdd() - adds or subtracts an interval from a date. For instance, DateAdd('year', Today(), -1) gives the date one year prior to today. The first argument to DateAdd is the level of granularity or date part.
- DateDiff() - determines the difference of the interval between two dates. DateDiff('day', [Start Date], [End Date]) returns the number of days separating the two date arguments.

The functions are well documented in the online help. Construct the formulas you need and filter accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Isolate yesterday's date as its own field. For instance if that is the max date in your data, then `{max([Date])}` would create an LOD of the maximum date.

Then make a calculation that will display the same date last year:

```
   year([Date]) = year([max_date])-1
    and datepart('week',[Date]) = datepart('week',[max_date])
    and datepart('weekday',[Date]) = datepart('weekday',[max_date])
```

Comment: When I tried this in the filter conditions, it said that the formula needed to be Boolean.  Also, what is LOD?

Comment: Do you want a date field as your result? LOD is Level of Detail calculation. They are really powerful. https://www.tableau.com/learn/whitepapers/understanding-lod-expressions

Comment: This is in the filter, I am trying to get tableau to automatically select the same day for yesterday but last year.  Example: 11 November 2018 (yesterday) would be 12 November 2017 (same day last year).  Both are Sunday.

Comment: Ok, I've edited my answer so the calc field is a boolean. Just removed the if and then date parts.